# Finding the browser width px and height px in (only) css

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if its possible to get the browser/viewport pixels dimentions of a page and display it on the page (preferably using a the "content" style) with just CSS. I'm doing this for a project of mine (completely built in CSS). I understand its quite easy to find it using JS, however thats not the point of this exercise.

One method I have produce is to use the help of a preprocessor to literally create media queries for each pixel through to a set amount such as 3000px as shown below.

```
/* WIDTH */
$width: 3000;

@for $i from 1 through $width {
    @media (min-width: #{$i}px) {.stat__size-width:after {content: "#{$i}px";}}
}
```

I don't care so much for optimisation and efficiency (as you can see by the current method it will create 3000+ css media queries and selectors just for width) however if there is a better way that I'm just overlooking please help me out!

---

Here you can see the project in more detail: http://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/NPZMdo

Comment: CSS cannot detect anything...it can only style things based on rules. You need javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D not completely true. Through media queries we can detect a range of browser statistics (orientation, height x width, colour profiles etc) however displaying these to the user is the issue. Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: If you're using Python then it isn't really CSS only...

Comment: @AaronVanston CSS doesn't do the detection, the device and/or browser does and applies the CSS that fits that detection.

Comment: @Shikkediel sass is only used to generate the absurd amount of media queries needed. It still sticking to CSS only by not using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 100vh or 100vw

This grabs 100% viewport height, and 100% viewport width

Comment: Is there a way to transform this 100vh into a pixel or numerical value that can be displayed in a 'content:' css property? i.e content: 100vh;

Comment: I think there is not with pure css.

Comment: You'd need javascript @AaronVanston , it will read the viewport sizes for you but it is not built to spit them back.